# React-native, firestore: how to update component state when an instance variable changes its value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google Firestore as my backend with React Native.

I created a class where I'm storing everything about firestore (methods, info, etc..) and I'm using the real-time updates (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) in that class:

```
class Fire{
  constructor() {
    this.user = {};  //is defined when the user log in
    this.userDocument = null;
  }

  _getRealTimeData = () => {
    const realTimeDatabaseRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.user.uid);
    realTimeDatabaseRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
      try {
        if (doc.exists) {
         this.userDocument = doc.data();
        } else {
          this.userDocument = null;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.userDocument = null;
      }
    });
  };
}
Fire = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

So this is working fine, whenever I update my firestore database, I automatically get the new value and store it in: 
    `this.userDocument`

The thing is that when this value changes the react-native component does not update, obviously it is because the state of that component is not updating.

So my question is, how can I notify my component that the value of "this.userDocument" in Fire class has changed? so then I can update the state by this.setState({userDocument: Fire.userDocument}).

Note: Right now I just get the data from "this.userDocument" in componentDidMount():

```
import Fire, { db } from "../../Fire";
export default class Profile extends Component {
    state={ userDocument:null }
    componentDidMount(){
      Fire._getRealTimeData()
      this.setState({userDocument: Fire.userDocument})
    }
  render(){...whatever I render}
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `_getRealTimeData`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to write that is edited now. in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your state at { Profile } change only at componentDidMount, therefore there is nothing that tells to this component that it should be rendered again.

I don't know what is the action that user use to update his profile data at firebase, but at the end of that add something like

---

```
  if (this.state.userDocument != Fire.userDocument)
                   this.setState({userDocument: Fire.userDocument})
```

---

if the action is at { Profile }, if it is in one of the child send this function and state as props, or of course add Redux to project and then store the state there and connect component to store and it gonna update automatically

Answer (score 1):

a) you can pass a callback to Fire and call it to set state on you Profile component.

b) pass a Promise to Fire component and resolve/reject it to set state to Profile component.